# Fourier transform and Full Width Half Maximum

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, scipy.stats

I'm trying to calculate the Fourier transform of three muon polarization signals, which are simply cosine functions multiplied by an exponential decay.
So, doing the Fourier transform, we are going to see broadened peaks centered at the corresponding frequency.
The problem is that I have already tried to do the Fourier transform, but I do not know if it's correct; furthermore, I'm trying to calculate the FWHM using the scipy.stats.moment function, using the 2-nd moment: is it correct?
Can you tell me if the code is correct?
I put here the three signals in .npy file and the code used for the Fourier analysis.
The signals are signal[0], signal[1] and signal[2], arrays of 10 dimension.
Each signal[k] contains 10 polarization functions (1 for each applied magnetic field), which are signals of 400 points.
The corresponding files are signal_100, signal_110, signal_111, provided here:
https://github.com/JonathanFrassineti/UNDI-examples.
Ah, the frequencies range from 0 Hz to 40 MHz.
Thank you!

```
N = 400 # Number of signal points.

N1 = 40000000

T = 1./800. # Sampling spacing.

xf = np.fft.rfftfreq(N1, T)
      
yf1 = FWHM1 = sigma1 = delta1 = bhar1 = np.zeros(fields, dtype = object)
yf2 = FWHM2 = sigma2 = delta2 = bhar2 = np.zeros(fields, dtype = object)
yf3 = FWHM3 = sigma3 = delta3 = bhar3 = np.zeros(fields, dtype = object)

for j in range(fields): 
    # Fourier transform.
    yf1[j] = np.fft.rfft(signal[0][j])
    yf2[j] = np.fft.rfft(signal[1][j])
    yf3[j] = np.fft.rfft(signal[2][j])
         
    FWHM1[j] = moment(yf1[j], moment=2)
    FWHM2[j] = moment(yf2[j], moment=2)
    FWHM3[j] = moment(yf3[j], moment=2)
    
    sigma1[j] = np.sqrt(np.abs(FWHM3[j]))/2.355
    sigma2[j] = np.sqrt(np.abs(FWHM2[j]))/2.355
    sigma3[j] = np.sqrt(np.abs(FWHM3[j]))/2.355
    
    delta1[j] = sigma1[j]/gamma_Cu
    delta2[j] = sigma2[j]/gamma_Cu
    delta3[j] = sigma3[j]/gamma_Cu
        
    bhar1[j] = (((a*angtom)**3)/(1e-7*gamma_Cu*hbar))*delta1[j]
    bhar2[j] = (((a*angtom)**3)/(1e-7*gamma_Cu*hbar))*delta2[j]
    bhar3[j] = (((a*angtom)**3)/(1e-7*gamma_Cu*hbar))*delta3[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently i work in a python project with same object. I've a set of data of magnetic field B(x,y,z), i think ideal would be to organize your data periodically at event and deduce Fe (sampling_rate).

```
f(A, t)=A*( cos(2*pi*fe*t) - sin(2*pi*fe*t) 

B=[ 50, 50, 10, 3 ] # where each data is |B| normal at second 
res=[ f(a, time) for time, a in enumerate(B) ]
fourrier_transform=np.fft.fft( res )
frequency= fftfreq([ time for time in range(len(B)) ]) # U can use fftfreq provide by scipy
```

Please star this project, research ressource to contribute

[RFSignalToolkit github project](https://github.com/Maissacrement/RFSignalToolkit)